# what is .gnt file, and how to convert .gnt file to .png file

Tags: python, deep-learning

I use CASIA Online and Offline Chinese Handwriting Databases, the picture of the character is in .gnt file.I wonder how to open it and convert it into .png file for deep learning training.

[www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/databases/handwriting/Download.html](http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/databases/handwriting/Download.html)

I am trying to convert the .gnt file to .png file. but I don't know how to do that
what's more, I 'm using ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I don't think you're going to find any existing conversion software.  This .GNT is a *very* specialized format, not useful for anything other than individual samples of handwritten Chinese characters; I doubt that anyone else in the world other than this one website uses it.  The format is documented on the "Offline Database" page of the site if you want to try writing a converter yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answers.I would ask the author about it